Nineties TV Show About Preventing Crimes
Okay, so as I remember it, the show was on TV in the UK on BBC2 in the second half of the nineties.  It was American and would have been a standard 45 minute episode as it was in the tea time slot.  
I don't remember much other than the pilot episode started with a light aircraft crashing into the White House and the President being killed as a result.
After this I think some crack team of scientists rushed through an experimental time travel program, hired a washed up military man who had psychological issues, sent him back in time and saved the day.
The team themselves had a leader (I think with beard), smart nerd (older guy with glasses?) and "hot" scientist who may have been European?
Not too much to go on, but hoping this will be enough for someone.

Sounds like the pilot of Seven Days, that ran on UPN in 1998-2001.

The President and Vice President were killed in a terrorist attack. Now it seems that a secret branch of the government has in their possession technology from the alien landing at Roswell, and they were able to use it to create a time machine that can send someone back in time seven days. And they would like to send someone back before this happened and tell what's going to happen before it does so they can prevent it. Now all they need is someone to send back, as the trip is excruciating. Frank Parker is an ex-Navy SEAL and CIA operative who has been confined to a mental hospital. He has been chosen as their "chrononaut" (or time traveler), as he has a high tolerance for pain, but at the same time he's a bit of a wildcard, as he doesn't like to be told what to do, or follow rules. 

The team is pretty much as you described them. Here's the intro:




Eventually the show turns into a rendition of Every Which Way but Loose
